# Android: Users comment implementation

Tags: android, mysql

Hi my app lets users post/share photos, and comment. App and server communicate via JSON. I'm looking for an effective way to let users know if there are new comments and mark as read after they read them.

I have a comment table on the server, do I add a column with *tinyint* as 'read' boolean? And how do I automatically set a comment record to true when they are accessed/selected?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since your app nature shows that you need to save read/unread status on server side (also other desired information). So whenever your server get to know that some User **A** has posted a comment for some User **B** you will send a push notification to **B** telling the app that a new Comment has been posted. When user click the comment to read it just send a notification to server telling him that this comment has been read and server will mark it read in its database. Thatz it